# How to set home directory when opening new tab in Terminal?

Tags: command-line, home-directory

Using Ubuntu 18.04.2.

When opening a new tab with Alt T, it opens the new tab in the same directory as the original window.

How to force it to always open in home directory?

Answer (score 2):

You could get a similar behavior to this by adding `cd $HOME` to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file.  Technically, this will cause any new shell to `cd $HOME`, which might might not be a great idea.

You can run `cd` by itself and it will return you to your home directory.

You haven't mentioned which terminal you're using, so assuming that you're using `gnome-terminal`, there should be a way to define custom shortcuts/commands. Others are using this with `--working-directory=` pointing to their home directories:

`gnome-terminal --working-directory=$HOME`